# How do I create the next two nested for loops?

Tags: c++

This is my program, and my goal is to output all of the class information in a specific format.

Example of the format I have to output the Information in:

```
Coltrane, John: 4, 18:37
        Giant Steps: 4, 18:37
                1. Giant Steps: 4:46
                3. Countdown: 2:25
                6. Naima: 4:24
                7. Mr. P.C.: 7:02
Lyle, Bobby: 1, 5:16
        Night Breeze: 1, 5:16
                5. Naima: 5:16
Puente, Tito: 1, 4:02
        El Rey: 1, 4:02
                5. Giant Steps: 4:02
Tjader, Cal: 1, 5:36
        A Fuego Vivo: 1, 5:36
                6. Naima: 5:36
Walton, Cedar: 4, 30:44
        Eastern Rebellion: 1, 8:38
                2. Naima: 8:38
        Naima: 3, 22:06
                2. This Guy's In Love With You: 8:10
                4. Down In Brazil: 6:07
                6. Naima: 7:49
```

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Song {
  public:
    string title;
    int time;
    int track;
};

class Album {
  public:
    map <int, Song > songs;
    string name;
    int time = 0;
};

class Artist {
  public:
    map <string, Album > albums;
    string name;
    int time = 0;
    int nsongs = 0;
};

int stringToInt(string s) {
    int i = 0;

    i += ((s.c_str())[0] - '0') * 60;
    i += ((s.c_str())[2] - '0') * 10;
    i += ((s.c_str())[3] - '0');

    return i;
}

string intToString(int i) {
    string s;
    int m, s1, s2;
    char m1, m2, s1c, s2c;

    m = i / 60;
    i -= m * 60;
    s1 = i / 10;
    i -= s1 * 10;
    s2 = i;

    if (m < 10) {
        m2 = m + '0';
        s.push_back(m2);
    }
    else {
        m1 = (m / 10) + '0';
        m2 = (m % 10) + '0';
        s.push_back(m1);
        s.push_back(m2);
    }
    s1c = s1 + '0';
    s2c = s2 + '0';
    s.push_back(':');
    s.push_back(s1c);
    s.push_back(s2c);

    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    string filename = argv[1];
    ifstream fin;
    string title, time, artist, album, genre;
    int track;
    map <string, Artist > artists;
    int numArtists = 0;


    fin.open(filename);
    while (fin >> title >> time >> artist >> album >> genre >> track) {
        Artist curArtist;
        Song curSong;
        Album curAlbum;


        replace(title.begin(), title.end(), '_', ' ');
        replace(artist.begin(), artist.end(), '_', ' ');
        replace(album.begin(), album.end(), '_', ' ');

        curSong.title = title;
        curSong.track = track;
        curSong.time = stringToInt(time);

        curAlbum.name = album;
        artists[artist].albums[album].time += stringToInt(time);

        artists[artist].nsongs++;
        artists[artist].time += stringToInt(time);


        if (artists.find(artist) != artists.end()) {
        if (artists[artist].albums.find(album) != artists[artist].albums.end()) {
            }
            else {
                artists[artist].albums.insert({album, curAlbum});
            }
        }
        else {
            artists.insert({artist, curArtist});

            artists[artist].albums.insert({album, curAlbum});
        }


        artists[artist].name = artist;

        artists[artist].albums[album].songs[track] = curSong;

    }

   for(map<string, Artist >::const_iterator it = artists.begin(); it != artists.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->first << ": " << it->second.nsongs << ", " << intToString(it->second.time) << "\n";
    }
}
```

I am able to loop through the artists lexicographically in a for loop, but I need to do that two more times. Considering I used an iterator in the first full loop, and referenced the map directly because it is local, I don't know how to do the same process with my maps that are not local.

link to the file to sort: [music.txt](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Ejplank/plank/classes/cs302/Labs/Lab1/Music.txt)

Comment: *which would theoretically take forever* -- Unless you plan on having thousands of names, with thousands of titles, with thousands of tracks, this will not take "forever".  If anything, the only thing slow would be the speed of the console.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this assignment calls for us sorting through a file a thousands of songs.

Comment: A thousand items in this day and age of computing is small.  Talk about millions, and maybe you will see issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yeah but a triple for loop (O(n^3)) with thousands of items means millions of processes

Comment: It is not necessarily `O(n^3)` .  You mentioned you have thousands of artists.  Does each artist have thousands of album, and does each of those albums have thousands of tracks?

Comment: Only if there are a thousand of items in every one of he thousand of items that are in every one of the thousand items in the top level container. This is clearly not the case here.

Comment: Yeah, that's true

Comment: can you post the file where all the data stored

Comment: @IanBurns Unless you changed the design, how else could you achieve this if you didn't use a triple nested for-loop?  You have to walk the entire structure anyway to print all the information.  The only thing I could think of is to cache the output, i.e. generate it once, but if asked to output the information again, you have everything cached without having to run a triple-nested loop gathering all the information.  But with that, you need to update the cache if the data has changed in some way.

Comment: @IanBurns -- *link to the file to sort:* -- Maybe you should consider using a database?  It is designed for things like this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've never used a database and don't have time to learn how unfortunately.

Comment: *I am able to loop through the artists lexicographically in a for loop, but I know I can't do that three times.*  -- You should post all of your code, including your attempt of doing this.  Right now, it is just speculation as to how long it takes to output the information.

Comment: Care should be done when talking about complexity, as what represent `N`. if N is total number of songs, so it is `O(n)`. else, we have to use several variables (as none are constrained by other), so `O(ArtisteCount*AlbumByArtistCount*SongByAlbumCount)`...

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a display method for each objects and call them from it's "owner" objects like this. It'll display the desired output wihout writing a big loop.

```cpp
class Song {
public:
  string title;
  int time;
  int track;

  void display() {
    printf("                %d. %s: %d\n", track, title.c_str(), time);
  }

};

class Album {
public:
  map <int, Song > songs;
  string name;
  int time = 0;

  void display() {
    printf("        %s: %d, %d\n", name.c_str(), (int)songs.size(), time);
    for (auto it = songs.begin(); it != songs.end(); ++it) {
      it->second.display();
    }
  }

};

class Artist {
public:
  map <string, Album > albums;
  string name;
  int time = 0;
  int nsongs = 0;

  void display() {
    printf("%s: %d, %d\n", name.c_str(), nsongs, time);
    for (auto it = albums.begin(); it != albums.end(); ++it) {
      it->second.display();
    }
  }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  map<string, Artist> artists;

  for (auto it = artists.begin(); it != artists.end(); ++it) {
    it->second.display();
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `printf` in a C++ program?

Comment: I guess I was convinced I had to do it without functions like that, but considering how easy that is, I like that answer

Comment: It still is a triple nesting, just in disguise.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what's wrong with printf? And yeah I know it's still a triple for loop but it is easier to read.

Comment: @IanBurns -- `printf` is not typesafe

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie till c++20 we don't have formated strings, so printf is my goto

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my professor must really be steering me in the wrong direction because he loves printf.

Comment: `printf("        %s: %d, %d\n", name.c_str(), (int)songs.size(), time);` --> `std::cout << "        " << name << ": " <<songs.size() << ", " << time;`.  That has worked with any standard of C++.

Comment: Also, C++ would use `std::ostream` and not `printf`, as that is much more flexible if you wanted to output the information to something other than the console.  In that regard, an overload of `operator <<` would be done on those classes that output information.

Comment: @IanBurns Guess you're trying to use the intToString function inside any of those classes, in that case you have to forward declare the function before the classes or simply move the function definition above the class

Comment: `display()` should be `const`.

Comment: for-range might replace those old for-loop.